# Open Link in other tab, but named, so that same tab is used each time

Tags: itext

In itext you can open a link using app.launchURL. This gives an extra parameter to open it in new tab. 
We want to open the url in a new tab, but each time the same tab. Just like you can do in normal a href by setting the target to a named tab.

Is this possible? 
Thanks in advance! Kind Regards, Marieke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no such functionality in ISO-32000-1. The best chance at finding a way to do this, is by looking at the JavaScript specification.

Incidentally, I have a copy of the unpublished ISO spec "ECMAScript for PDF" (currently in development at the ISO meeting in Pretoria). This is what it says:

> **launchURL —** Launches a URL in a browser window.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - *cURL —* A string that specifies the URL to launch.
> - *bNewFrame —* (optional) If `true`, this method launches the URL in a new window of the browser application. The default is `false`.

I think it's safe to say that you're asking for something that is impossible. If it were possible, the spec would mention an extra parameter to define the name of the tab or window.

(This answer isn't limited to iText; what you're trying isn't possible in general.)

Comment: Hi Bruno, any help on the question in current time.